# Splay trees: why are depths of nodes on the access path halved?

Tags: data-structures, trees, binary-trees, splay-trees

The original paper describing splay trees [Self-Adjusting Binary Search Trees](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~sleator/papers/self-adjusting.pdf) by Sleator and Tarjan claims that:

> Splaying not only moves x to the root, but roughly halves the depth of every node along the access path.

What is the intuition for this claim? The paper includes some figures (splaying in a tree of all zig-zigs or all zig-zags) and while I can see at a high level that splaying helps other parts of the tree, it's not really clear to me where the halving comes from?

Answer (score 1):

Nobody has answered this question yet, and I can give some hints how to solve it.
I would much rather post this as a comment, but I can't since I don't have enough reputation.

So here is a link to the original paper: [https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~sleator/papers/self-adjusting.pdf](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Esleator/papers/self-adjusting.pdf)

The basic idea is looking at zig-zig and zig-zag (zig only happens once when the parent of x is the root!):

[image: zig-zig]

1. Notice that if a node was in the search path before x was pushed to that position, it is now either in A or in B.
2. Notice that all nodes in A and B have at least **1 depth less** than before the zig-zig operation

[image: zig-zag]

1. Notice that if a node was in the search path before x was pushed to that position, it is now either in B or in C.
2. Notice that all nodes in B and C have at least **1 depth less** than before the zig-zag operation

Now just think about how many zig-zig and zig-zag operations there are for a node with depth d in the search path.